# Updating a Column and introducing a condition

Tags: oracle10g

Basic question, beginning user.

I have a column (price) in a table (room).  The column (price) has a constraint that it has to be between 20 and 100.

I need to update the column (price) to reflect a price increase of 5%.  However, some of the fields in this column will have a price >100 after the update, causing it to fall 
outside of the constraint.  To address this, those prices that exceed 100 need to be set to 100 instead.  Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE ROOM
SET PRICE=
CASE 
   WHEN PRICE*1.05<100 
   THEN PRICE*1.05
   ELSE PRICE=100
END CASE
WHERE HOTELNO='1004' OR
      HOTELNO='1001' OR
      HOTELNO='1002'
;
```

Best I could come up with in my searches.  I am getting the following error:

ORA-00905: missing keyword

This is using Oracle 10g.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following

```
update room
set price=price*1.05
where hotelno in ('1004','1001')
and (price*1.05)<100
```

Comment: Why does it look so obvious after you see the answer??  THANKS!